# Reading the Value Attribute of a Checkbox in Flask/WTF

Tags: python, forms, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a form with a column of checkboxes corresponding to the columns in my database. I'm setting the value of each checkbox (in javascript) to the name of the column, but when I try to read the checkbox value in Flask/Python all I can get is `True` or `False`. How do I read the text value of the `value` attribute of the checkboxes?

Just to complicate things, I'm generating the form as a FieldList of FormFields, so I can't simply hardcode the field names. (Well, I could, but that would make it fragile to schema changes.)

My form code is

```
class ImportFilterSubForm(Form):
    use = BooleanField(
        'Use', 
        render_kw={'class': 'use'}
    )
    sel = SelectField(
        'Maps to:', 
        choices=[], 
        render_kw={'class': 'sel'}, 
        validators=[Optional()]
    )

class ImportFilterForm(FlaskForm):
    rows = FieldList(FormField(ImportFilterSubForm))
```

My view code, with error handling removed, is

```
def prefilter_import():
    db_columns = Contact.__table__.columns.keys()
    filename = request.cookies.get('workfile')
    with open(filename) as fh:
        reader = csv.DictReader(fh)
        file_columns = reader.fieldnames
    
    form = ImportFilterForm()
    for col in db_columns:
        new_row = form.rows.append_entry()
        new_row.use.label = col
        new_row.sel.choices = file_columns
    
    input_file = request.cookies.get('input_file')
    return render_template('filter_import.html', form=form, filename=input_file)

def postfilter_import():
    form = ImportFilterForm()

    db_columns = Contact.__table__.columns.keys()
    filename = request.cookies.get('workfile')
    with open(filename) as fh:
        reader = csv.DictReader(fh)
        file_columns = reader.fieldnames
    
    missing_columns = db_columns
    extra_columns = file_columns
    
    mappings = dict()
    for i, row in enumerate(form.rows):
        if row.use.data:  # Problem arises here
            mappings[row.use.data] = row.sel.data
    
    for key, value in mappings.items():
        missing_columns.remove(key)  # Problem manifests here
        extra_columns.remove(value)
```

I'm trying to create a dict mapping the values of the checkboxes to the values of the selects, but I'm only getting `True` and `False` for the checkboxes, even though I've verified that the checkboxes' `value` attributes are correctly returned as the names of the corresponding columns.

How can I get Flask/WTForms to return the text of the `value` attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, I discovered the `raw_data` attribute of the field object, which contains a list of the values of the `value` attributes of the HTML control. Thus, the code

```
    mappings = dict()
    for row in form.rows:
        if row.use.data:
            mappings[row.sel.data] = row.use.raw_data[0]
    
    for key, value in mappings.items():
        missing_columns.remove(value)
        extra_columns.remove(key)
```

does what I need it to do.

Comment: Thank you, Stack Exchange, for allowing me to use you as my debugging rubber duck.